# How can I use saucelabs connect with circle-ci 2.0?

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, circleci, webdriver-io, saucelabs

In circle-ci 1.0 the config file seemed to specify dependencies. I noticed that in circle-ci 2.0 that this concept is gone to some degree.

Sooo I tried the following:

```
  steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Sauce Connect
          command: |
            wget https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
            tar -xzf sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
      ...
      - run: yarn integration
```

Seems like this didn't quite pan out. I get the following result in circle-ci's console:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
yarn run integration
yarn run v0.24.6
$ node_modules/.bin/wdio test/wdio.conf.js 

A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Could not start Sauce Connect. Exit code 1 signal: null
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/sauce-connect-launcher/lib/sauce-connect-launcher.js:559:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)

Continue...
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4445
chrome
Error
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4445
chrome
Error

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 1
```

I'm using wdio, with the sauce and mocha plugins. It works locally. Ideas? Any guides that exist anywhere for this? Google didn't produce any answers for circle-ci 2.0 and saucelabs integrations.